# VB.NET Exception Occurs When Trying To View DataGridView

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, oledb

I have a very simple table in access. The data is stored from VB.NET using the OLEDB adapter. I have a second form which has just a single DataGridView which was dragged/dropped using VS2010 from the Data Sources window.

When trying to view the window the first time no data is shown and the second time an exception occurs and the program closes.

Here is the automatically generated code:

```vb
Public Class ViewSent

Private Sub SentBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SentBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.SentBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DbDataSet)
End Sub

Private Sub ViewSent_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DbDataSet.Sent' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.SentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbDataSet.Sent)


 End Sub

End Class
```

The specific column I am facing issues with is a "Text" formatted column and the data being inserted is:

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("Time", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString().Trim()
```

In the Immediate window after clicking the Form.ShowDialog() button this message appears:
A first chance exception of type `'System.ArgumentException'` occurred in System.Data.dll

Also, the data does not load into the datagridview.

After closing the window and then clicking the same button (Not data has been changed at all) this error appears:
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <07/11/2011 00:55:06> in Time Column.  Expected type is Int32.

Comment: What is the data type of that column in your data store?

Comment: The datatype is Text and is being stored as text:
md2.Parameters.Add("Time", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString().Trim(). If it was an issue storing the data then this issue would occur upon the insert, instead it is an issue with displaying the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what Givelasdougmore is trying to say is, that you shouldnt use Words like "Time" "Update" "Delete" as Columnname in your database

Try to change the column name  "Time" to something like "Creationdatetime" or something like this. Then everything should work

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed the column name before, then reconfigured the datasource but each time it was still getting the column name of Time until I finally restarted my PC and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the datatype does match the ones at the database as will as the ones in the dataset.

Comment: The datatype is Text and is being stored as text:
md2.Parameters.Add("Time", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString().Trim().